# html5 video overlay to follow cursor

Tags: php, html5-video, lamp, interactive

I have a question for the brilliant stack overflow collective.  It is a little difficult to describe my question, so I will start from the beginning.  I have a LAMP server running Ubuntu Server 14. The project I am working on involves the following steps:

1. the server accepts an anonymous video upload
2. the server displays the video to the user
3. the user clicks somewhere on the video to select a vertical column of the video to analyze
4. the vertical coordinate corresponding to the click is then passed onto the server
5. the video is analyzed with ffmpeg/imagmagick shell script and a corresponding image is created
6. final image is displayed to the user

I have set up a PHP upload page set up that will display the video to the user with standard html5.

**What I am working on now:** For usability I'm trying to set up an overlay on the html5 video that is a vertical line, 1-3 pixels thick 50% transparency, that moves with the cursor as it hovers over the playing video, so the user knows exactly what column he is selecting. Is there a way to implement this in html5?  I just don't know where to start or look for this.  Also, how can i capture the coordinate variable and pass it on to my shell script?

Comment: I don't know but your name is funny

Comment: I'd look into displaying your video on a canvas: http://html5doctor.com/video-canvas-magic/

Comment: Think of the video as a normal html element of fixed width and height . It will only be a problem if the video size was dynamic.

Comment: The video size is variable.  I cannot predict what clip will be uploaded.

Comment: I had considered making a custom cursor for hover-over, this might be the easiest option. http://www.sitepoint.com/css3-cursor-styles/ But it won't look clean if the cursor extends past the edge of the canvas.